# Read/Write a typed array to file with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typed-arrays

I have the following typed array: `Uint16Array(2) [ 60891, 11722 ]` which I would like to save to a (binary) file. I would then like to read it back into another Uint16Array with the order of the elements preserved.

I tried using the `fs` module but when I go to read the file I'm not getting the same integers:

```js
//console.log(buffer) : Uint16Array(2) [ 60891, 11722 ]
fs.writeFileSync(bufferPath, buffer, 'binary')
const loadedBuffer = fs.readFileSync(bufferPath)
//console.log(new Uint16Array(loadedBuffer)) : Uint16Array(4) [ 219, 237, 202, 45 ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_typedarray) class is a subclass of JavaScript's `Uint8Array` class and not a `Uint16Array` array as you commented in your code. To obtain a copy of the original `Uint16Array` array you can use the `new Uint16Array(buffer, byteOffset, length)` constructor like mentioned in the [`Uint16Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint16Array/Uint16Array) documentation:

```
let arr = new Uint16Array(loadedBuffer.buffer, loadedBuffer.byteOffset, loadedBuffer.length / 2);
```

Comment: In case anyone else needs this: for the case where the buffer is retrieved using a fetch e.g `const response = await fetch(bufferPath); const buffer = response.arrayBuffer()` It seems `new Uint16Array(buffer)` will work

Comment: @Dianne Nice observation.